# combining three graphs

Tags: graphics

I want to combine three graphs ,one up and two down , I have problem making 
the whole graph appropriate

I attach graph for the result I get so you can understand my problem

I add a code of the same data for three graphs so you can run

[image: My result]

the code

```
data = {0.0355629000148645`, 0.`, 0.10404720022877754`, 0.`, 
 0.16556061834582467`, 0.`, 0.21791027604133678`, 0.`, 
 0.2609014672890685`, 0.`,
 0.2954995803446824`, 0.`, 0.3230517086312041`, 0.`, 
 0.3448427814130384`, 0.`, 0.36192764181747616`, 0.`, 
 0.37511122444617473`, 0.`, 0.3849867998456937`,
 0.`, 0.39198711022720617`, 0.`, 0.39643056691123285`, 0.`, 
 0.3985576225141368`};

 num = {3.`, 4.`, 5.`, 6.`, 7.`, 8.`, 9.`, 10.`, 11.`, 12.`, 13.`, 
 14.`, 15.`, 16.`, 17.`, 18.`, 19.`, 20.`, 21.`, 22.`, 23.`, 24.`, 
 25.`, 26.`, 27.`, 28.`, 29.`};


 data = Flatten[data];

  num = Flatten[num];

  d1 = Table[{num[[i]], data[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[num]}];


 a = ListLinePlot[{d1}, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, Black}, 
 Frame -> True, PlotMarkers -> {\[FilledCircle], 7}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue]];

 b = ListPlot[{d1}, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, Black}, 
 Frame -> True, , PlotMarkers -> {\[FilledCircle], 7}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red]];


 c = ListPlot[{d1}, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, Black}, 
 Frame -> True, , PlotMarkers -> {\[FilledCircle], 7}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Directive[Green]];

 pic = Panel[GraphicsGrid[{{c}, {a, b}}], 
 Rotate["|\[LeftAngleBracket]\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Psi]\), \(0\ 
\), SubscriptBox[\(m\), \(f\)]]\)|\!\(\*SubscriptBox[OverscriptBox[\(\
    \[CapitalEta]\), \(^\)], \(k\)]\)|\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Psi]\), \
\(0\), \((1)\)]\)\[RightAngleBracket]|", 90 Degree], Left, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, Black, "Times"}, Background -> White,
 FrameMargins -> 0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I not sure this is what you want. Play with `ImageSize`

```
data = {0.0355629000148645`, 0.`, 0.10404720022877754`, 0.`, 
       0.16556061834582467`, 0.`, 0.21791027604133678`, 0.`, 
       0.2609014672890685`, 0.`, 0.2954995803446824`, 0.`, 
       0.3230517086312041`, 0.`, 0.3448427814130384`, 0.`, 
       0.36192764181747616`, 0.`, 0.37511122444617473`, 0.`, 
       0.3849867998456937`, 0.`, 0.39198711022720617`, 0.`, 
       0.39643056691123285`, 0.`, 0.3985576225141368`};

num = {3.`, 4.`, 5.`, 6.`, 7.`, 8.`, 9.`, 10.`, 11.`, 12.`, 13.`, 
   14.`, 15.`, 16.`, 17.`, 18.`, 19.`, 20.`, 21.`, 22.`, 23.`, 24.`, 
   25.`, 26.`, 27.`, 28.`, 29.`};



d1 = Transpose[{num, data}];


a = ListLinePlot[d1, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, Black}, 
   Frame -> True, PlotMarkers -> {\[FilledCircle], 7}, 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue], ImageSize -> 300, 
   ImagePadding -> {{40, 1}, {40, 30}}];

b = ListPlot[d1, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, Black}, 
   Frame -> True, PlotMarkers -> {\[FilledCircle], 7}, 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red], ImageSize -> 300, 
   ImagePadding -> {{40, 1}, {40, 30}}];


c = ListPlot[d1, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, Black}, 
   Frame -> True, PlotMarkers -> {\[FilledCircle], 7}, 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Directive[Green], ImageSize -> 630, 
   ImagePadding -> {{40, 1}, {40, 1}}];

pic = Labeled[
  Column[{c, Row[{a, b}, Spacer@20, Alignment -> Top]}, 
   Alignment -> Left], 
  Style["|\[LeftAngleBracket]\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Psi]\), \(0\ 
   \), SubscriptBox[\(m\), \
\(f\)]]\)|\!\(\*SubscriptBox[OverscriptBox[\(    \[CapitalEta]\), \
\(^\)], \(k\)]\)|\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Psi]\), \(0\), \((1)\)]\
\)\[RightAngleBracket]|", 30, Black, "New York Times"], Left, 
  RotateLabel -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: yes this is what I meant ,thanks a lot